# Routing from VM to internet

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, routing

I have setup a VM using VirtualBox with Windows 7 as the host. On my homenetwork the VM can connect fine to the internet, without any changes on my side. However, when I'm running the VM when connected to my company network, I can not reach any address on the internet (DNS works fine).

Now I read on the documentation of VirtualBox, that the NAT setting effectively works like a router. So I assume that I have to setup some additional route in order to be able to use the internet from inside the VM. Am I correct that the setup looks like this?

```
VM goes to Host Virtual Network card vom VirtualBox
VBNetwork card goes to the internet directly.
```

Now when I'm connected to my company net, apparently the VBox card can not connect directly to the internet, so I would think that I maybe have to tell it how it can route, but how can I do this?

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      16.61.244.1     10.61.246.13     10
      10.61.244.0    255.255.252.0         On-link      10.61.246.13    266
     10.61.246.13  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.61.246.13    266
    10.61.247.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.61.246.13    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.3.153    276
    169.254.3.153  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.3.153    276
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.3.153    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     169.254.3.153    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.61.246.13    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.3.153    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.61.246.13    266
===========================================================================

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : corporate.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:fff:420f:a229%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.61.246.13
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.61.244.1

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:6da0:399%17
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.3.153
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Answer (score 0):

In the network settings for the virtual machine you can configure a `bridged` network adapter.  This will enable your virtual machine to access the internet.

Comment: I tried that as well, but the result is the same. The VM can not access the internet, because of the company LAN setup.

Comment: If the company is restricting the LAN network there isn't really much you can do.

Comment: But can't I route my VB traffic to the real network? Because I can use the internet, I just can't get through in the VM. So I have the feeling that this is just a problem with the setup, but I'm not good at networking, so I couldn't find out how to fix it.